# Two sequences have the same limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let  $f$ and $g$ be real-valued continuous functions on $\Bbb R^2$ that satisfy the following condition:
$$
x<y \implies x< f(x,y) < g(x,y) <y
$$
Assume that there are two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ that satisfy the following:
$$ a_1 < b_1, a_1,b_1 \in \Bbb R,\quad a_{n+1}=f(a_n, b_n),\quad b_{n+1}=g(a_n,b_n).
$$
It's easily seen that 
$$a_1 < a_2 < ...< a_n < ...< b_n < b_{n-1} < ... < b_1.$$
Hence $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$  are monotonic and bounded thus convergent. 
Now I want to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n= \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$.

**My attempt:** Assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=a, \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n=b$. 
Since $a_n < b_n$, $a \le b$. Since $a_{n+1}=f(a_n, b_n)$, we have $a=f(a,b)$.
If $a< b$ then $a < f(a,b)$, a contradiction.
It follows that $a=b$.

Does the proof above look fine?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @Asemismaiel My only concern is whether $a=f(a,b)$ if $a_{n+1}=f(a_n,b_n)$?

Comment: $\lim f(a_n, b_n) = f(a,b)$ follows from the continuity of $f(x,y)$, for if $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(a,b)$ then for any sequence converging to $(a,b)$ the sequence of the images of the sequence converge to $f(a,b)$. This is known as the sequential criterion of continuity.

Comment: And taking the limit of both sides is justified by the fact that they are the same sequence, of course.

Comment: @Asemismaiel Thanks for clearing up the confusion. I want to make this post answered. Would you mind adding your comments as an answer?

Comment: No problem, just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine to me.

$\lim f(a_n, b_n) = f(a,b)$ follows from the continuity of $f(x,y)$, for if $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(a,b)$ then for any sequence converging to $(a,b)$ the sequence of the images of the sequence converges to $f(a,b)$. This is known as the sequential criterion of continuity.